# How do you append just ONE random USER from array?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am of course using Firebase for my project. I have database with a bunch of "users" and I have returned all of the users, along with their "usernames" into my simple tableView. I was wondering, how do I pick a random user out of the array of users and just append that one user when I call my fetchUser() function in my viewDidLoad? Here's my tableView code and my Firebase code. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class NewMessageController: UITableViewController {

    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Chat"

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        fetchUser()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupViewWillAppear()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.username

        return cell
    }
}

    func fetchUser() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let user = User()

            user.username = dictionary["username"] as? String
            user.profile_image_url = dictionary["profile_image_url"] as? String

            self.users.append(user)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

load them all into an array, and generate a random number in the range 0..

```
indexUser = Int(arc4random_uniform(users.count))
```

then change `fetchUsers()` to return a single user, and

```
return self.users[indexUser]
```

Here's how you might change `fetchUser`

```
func fetchUser() -> User {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let user = User()

            user.username = dictionary["username"] as? String
            user.profile_image_url = dictionary["profile_image_url"] as? String

            self.users.append(user)
        }

        if self.users.count > 0
        {
            // You now have an array of users, so pick one
            return  self.users[Int(arc4random_uniform(self.users.count))]
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

If you want to continue displaying all users in the tableView, you will need to reload the table once you have your selected user

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you please provide an example? Thank you

Comment: Always happy to help